# Mask on a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Can anyone point me to an idea/direction on how to implement the masking layer on this one? I know that I should add the mask layer onto the `superview` instead on the `scrollView`, but how would the mask layer take the shape of the passing image?

[image]

Comment: What about a background view which is brown in the center and white elsewhere. And the imagesViews on your scrollView are transparent where there are the icons?

Comment: You can constrain the mask to the scrollview's `frameLayoutGuide` instead of the content layout guide and as @Larme said, use a background view with transparent icons.